# Crontab running before nfs mounted

Tags: linux, cron, nfs

Running Cronjob @reboot returns that file on nfs share does not exist.

Example

```
@reboot python /abs/path/to/script.py
```

mail from crontab on startup reads "more or less"

```
/usr/bin/python can't open file "/abs/path/to/script.py": [Error No. 2] No such file or folder.
```

Script can be run from the command line with no trouble..
Theory is that the cronjob is running before mount has been run.
The questions.

1. Is this theory correct?
2. Is there a way to force the job to wail until the drive has been mounted? .... Other than just putting in a sleep 60 into the command. ;) I tried that already, but it's hit and miss and I need the script to run 100% of the time quickly.

Comment: What distribution are you using?

Comment: [Make mount-folders immutable](https://serverfault.com/a/570271).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the [mountpoint](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mountpoint) command to ensure the mount has taken place before you execute your command e.g.  (assuming /abs is the mount point)

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    if mountpoint -q /abs
        then
            /usr/bin/python /abs/path/to/script.py
            break
        fi
    sleep 10
done
```

Comment: +1 I've never heard of `mountpoint` - this is quite useful!

Comment: @SvenW Same here. I'm now updating a handful of scripts with this.

Comment: Selecting this as the answer since while the system is rebooting, we don't even know if the nic is up to mount the system and attempting to mount the file system before the nic is ready can be disastrous.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what the problem is since cron starts after networking. (At least in Red Hat and derivatives.) Are your mounts in `/etc/fstab` with `_netdev` option or else where?

The standard way to execute something on start up is to include it in `/etc/rc.local`.  This will be ran after the network is initialized and all other services are started.  (Including mounting of remote file systems.)

(Or is there a reason to only execute the script after a literal reboot?)

Comment: Yes the share is mounted in fstab.  I was running in ubuntu, which means that the networking may not have been running.  etc/rc.local does seem to be the best solution, but if @restart exists in crontab, the assumption is that it should work.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ideas for you:

1. check if NFS is mounted. If not, mount it, then run your script:

   `[ ! -f /abs/path/to/script.py ] && mount -t nfs device dir &&
   python /abs/path/to/script.py`
2. run your script in the `start()` function of the NFS init script:

   ```
   echo -n $"Starting NFS mountd: "
   daemon rpc.mountd $RPCMOUNTDOPTS
   RETVAL=$?
   echo
   [ $RETVAL -ne 0 ] && exit $RETVAL || python /abs/path/to/script.py
   ```

Answer (score 1):

To be absolutely sure that the python script is able to run. You would need to wrap it in a script stored on local storage to verify that the mount point has come up.

Something like (warning pseudo code):

```
while (!ScriptExists && ErrorCount < 10)
do
    mount /my/mount/point
    sleep 10
    ErrorCount++
done
```