# NFS mounts depending on other NFS mount fail to mount at boot

Tags: linux, nfs, mount, fstab

I have setup 5 NFS mounts in `/etc/fstab`.

The first one "parent" mounts on local mount point `/foo` and the other 4 "child" in mounts points on the first one:

So let's say the second is `/foo/test1`.
The third is in `/foo/media` etc...

Example:

```
192.168.0.101:/adventure-time    /foo           some-nfs-options
192.168.0.101:/south-park        /foo/test1     some-nfs-options
192.168.0.101:/futurama          /foo/media     some-nfs-options
/etc./
```

But when i do `df -h` after logging in (after reboot) it shows only the share on `/foo`... the others (in the sub-directories) are not mounted... So i type `mount -a` and everything is fine...

I check `/var/log/messages` and i saw that during boot when it tries to mount the "child" nfs exports which depend on folders in the "parent" one it whines about "no local mounts points found". So i assume it takes some time (we are talking 1-2 seconds more) to mount `/adventure-time` in `/foo` so during that time the folders `test1` and `media` are not available... and therefore it fails to mount the other shares.Like it tries to mount everything at once...

Then after login when already these folders are present (because `/adventure-time` is already mounted in `/foo`) it mounts the other shares without problem (local mount points already exist)...

The question is how to make the "child" shares to be depending on the "parent" and wait for him to mount before they try?

Typing `mount -a` in `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` is only a workaround...

Is there some nfs option that i should put in fstab?

There has to be a solution for this? nfs (or the boot process) should not be that dumb... :/

Comment: What OS distribution is this?

Answer (score 2):

You want the `bg` mount option in `/etc/fstab`: this will cause the mounts which initially fail to background themselves and retry, when they will succeed.

Comment: Which OS' fstab is it that supports `bg` option? O_o

Comment: @poige: I'm not sure.  The [nfs(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nfs.5.html) entry you reach from kernel.org has it, but I don't have a RHEL distribution handy to check.  Solaris does, of course (it originated with SunOS 3 or 4 I should think)

Comment: @poige PS: I've just checked and Ubuntu certainly does, so I'm guessing that all Linux distros do at least.

Comment: (And I can confirm now that RHEL does, so OEL will too, as it is just RHEL outside the kernel.)

Answer (score 1):

> There has to be a solution for this? nfs (or the boot process) should not be that dumb

The boot process isn't dumb. I haven't read the man pages for mount/nfs in a while but I don't recall there being any way to make one mount dependent on another.

It seems that you already have one solution - using a script. You may want to look at the [mountpoint](https://serverfault.com/questions/436048/crontab-running-before-nfs-mounted/436059#436059) command which can help in this type of script.

Another solution might be [autofs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/s2-nfs-config-autofs.html). You would mount your main NFS filesystem using fstab as normal and then use autofs to mount the sub filesytems on demand.

Comment: Unfortunately autofs will not do since on the actual machine these exports are for oracle database... So they need to be mounted right away... Especially since database has autostart on... Failure to mount means failure on database = failure of the application running on the server :/

Comment: Failure to mention that leads to ... but anyway autofs should mount the stuff on first access - it may be worth trying. Failing that you're just going to have to go with a script. If you have dependencies on the mount points then you should consider using systemd unit files (or whatever your unspecified distro uses) and ensure that the unit runs before whatever starts oracle.

Comment: Distro is oracle enterprise linux 6 so init scripts.... I think the solution will involve nesting nfs but i cannot find any relevant info on the matter

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a redhat-like distribution, be sure to enable the `netfs` service.

This should take care of your nested mounts. Test and see.