# rsync: Don't create destination directory

Tags: rsync

I want to rsync my root directory to an external hard disk mounted under `/media/guettli/backup1t/`.

```
rsync -xavi --delete --delete-excluded \
  --exclude '...' \
  /  /media/guettli/backup1t/
```

Something went wrong with the mounting and rsync happily created `/media/guettli/backup1t/` in the root directory and rsynced copied files there and not onto the external hard drive.

I would like to avoid this.

I could do it with a shell script which checks that `/media/guettli/backup1t/` exists before starting rsync, but I would prefer an option to rsync.

How can I tell rsync to not start the sync, if the destination does not exist?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/436048/crontab-running-before-nfs-mounted/436059#436059

Answer (score 1):

You can try do something like that:

```
rsync -xavi --rsync-path="[[ -d /media/guettli/backup1t ]] && rsync" --delete --delete-excluded \
  --exclude '...' \
  /  /media/guettli/backup1t/
```